# Converting from decimal base to hexadecimal base

Tags: java

i have a question about transforming from decimal base to hexadecimal base in Java. I've done with part of code to transform from Decimal to Binary and Octal, but i've got some problems with hexadecimal, cause i don't know how to make the result to show with A, B, C, D, E and F. Here is mine code:

```
package transformare1;
import java.io.*;

public class Transformare1 {


    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println ("Introduceti un numar natural in baza 10 ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println ("Alegeti in ce baza sa fie convertit numarul: 2, 8, 16 ");
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       if (n1==2){
       String b = "";
        while (n!=0){
            int r = (int)(n%2);
            b = r+b;
            n /=2;
        }
        System.out.println ("Numarul binar este "+b);
       }
       else if (n1==8){
       String b = "";
       while (n!=0){
        int r = (int)(n%8);
        b = r+b;
        n /=8;
       }
       System.out.println ("Numarul octal este "+b);
    }
       else if (n1==16){
        String b ="";
        while (n!=0){
        int r = (int)(n%16);
        b = r+b;
        n /=16;
        final char A=10;
        final char B=11;
        final char C=12;
        final char D=13;
        final char E=14;
        final char F=15;
        }
        System.out.println ("Numarul hexadecimal este "+b);   
       }}

}
```

Comment: Simplest approach is to define a string "0123456789ABCDEF" and use charAt to access the character corresponding to a 4-bit "nybble" from your source number.  Or simply use the support in Integer class.

Comment: Ooh, sorry, @HotLicks, I didn't see that you had beaten me to it, when I posted my answer.  If you want to convert your comment to an answer, I'll remove mine, so that you get the credit.

Comment: I don't see how the others can work, though.  (OK, now I do, but it's a bit of a cheat.  You should add the char value `0` to r and cast to char before concatenating.)

Comment: Why not?  They're all using a standard algorithm.  Of course, I haven't tested this code, but it looks OK to me.

Comment: (Not a "standard algorithm" I'm familiar with, relying on string concatenation to convert a number to it's char representation.)

Comment: (Note that you can use one algorithm for all 3 by making the divisor a variable rather than a literal.  It doesn't hurt if the translation string is too long.)

Comment: Bit of a cheat?  No, cheating would be writing something like `(r < 10 ? '0' : '7' ) + (char)r`

Comment: @DavidWallace - Actually, that's just good programming.  The "cheat" is in doing string concat on an int and relying on concat to convert the int to a character.  Might as well just use Integer.toXxxString.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of fixing this.  One way is to replace `b = r+b` in the "hexadecimal" section of the code with `b = "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(r) + b`.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer